# Function objects as type fields in Julia

Tags: types, julia, function-object

Is it possible to store a function object as a member/field of a composite type in Julia 0.3.x?

Since it is possible to assign function objects to ordinary variables, this *seems* to be possible but I'm not sure how to determine the proper type (there is a `Function` type but I'm not sure if and how it can be refined to match e.g. functions with two `Int32` arguments, and if it's even the right type to consider) for such a field if I want it to have constraints on what argument types the stored function can have. TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Function` type is correct - Julia doesn't currently create a more specific type.